# Why is the hashtag #P3tra used in posts about Petra Kvitová

Tags: tennis, media

I have noticed that many twitter posts about [Petra Kvitová](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petra_Kvitov%C3%A1) use the [hashtag #P3tra](https://twitter.com/hashtag/P3tra).

What is origin of this hashtag? Is there some significance to this name (like 3 important wins or somethings similar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Petra Kvitová has [a record of playing the biggest number of three-set matches](http://www.wtatennis.com/news/article/3477775/title/stats-corner-kvitovas-three-setters), which is not something to be very proud of, I guess, but [it has earned her](http://www.tennisratings.co.uk/article---petra-kvitova---why-does-she-play-so-many-3-set-matches) the affectionate nickname “P3tra”.